# why when transmitting the jwt token in Bearer Token the role disappears Spring security?

Tags: jwt

I set up authentication with spring security using JWT. When I check the token on https://jwt.io it contains the user role, but when I have access to the resources with Bearer Token access is refused.THANKS

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{private String jwtKey = "key";
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    
    
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(this.jwtKey.getBytes(), 0, this.jwtKey.getBytes().length,"HS256");
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKey).macAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HS256).build();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(new ImmutableSecret<>(this.jwtKey.getBytes()));
    }

    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {        
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS))
                
                
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize  ->
                authorize  
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();       
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            HttpSecurity http,
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                                    .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();    
    }
}
``
```

@Service
public class JWTService {

```
private JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;

@Autowired
public JWTService(JwtEncoder jwtEncoder) {
    this.jwtEncoder = jwtEncoder;
}

public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        
        User principal = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = principal.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println("generer"+ roles);
        
        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                  .issuer("self")
                  .issuedAt(now)
                  .expiresAt(now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
                  .subject(authentication.getName())
                  .claim("roles", roles)
                  .build();
    JwtEncoderParameters jwtEncoderParameters = 
            JwtEncoderParameters.from(JwsHeader.with(MacAlgorithm.HS256).build(), claims);
    return this.jwtEncoder.encode(jwtEncoderParameters).getTokenValue();
    
}
```

}

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

```
@Autowired
private DBUserRepository dbUserRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    DBUser user = dbUserRepository.findByUsername(username);
    
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Utilisateur non trouvé avec le nom d'utilisateur: " + username);
    }

    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), getGrantedAuthorities(user.getRole()));
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(String role) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    return authorities;
}
```

}

```
I manage to connect and get the token
```